# having trouble with binding data back to the file

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularJS and trying to update a row of data in the view but somehow it appears not to do anything. the goal is to render the new row of data into my table.

thanks a lot!

```js
myBankApp.controller("displayClients",function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('/data/clients.json').then(function(response){
     $scope.list= response.data;
   });
    $scope.addClient=function(){
        $scope.list.push({
          name: $scope.client.name,
          lastName: $scope.client.lastName,
          bankAccountNumber: $scope.client.bankAccountNumber,
          balance:$scope.client.balance
    
        })
        $scope.client.name="";
        $scope.client.lastName="";
        $scope.client.bankAccountNumber="";
        $scope.client.balance="";
    }
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="displayClients">
   <table>
       <tr>
         <th>first name</th>
         <th>last name</th>
         <th>account number</th>
         <th>balance</th>
       </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat= " x in list">
           <td> {{x.name}}</td>
           <td> {{x.lastName}}</td>
           <td> {{x.bankAccountNumber}}</td>
           <td> {{x.balance}}</td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</div>   
<br>
<form ng-submit="addClient() ng-controller="displayClients"">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="client.name"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="lastName" ng-model="client.lastName"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="account" ng-model="client.bankAccountNumber"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="balance" ng-model="client.balance"/>
    <input type="submit" value="add client">
</form>
```

Comment: It's just a theory, but I think you're passing references to the array instead of values. Try something like `name: angular.copy($scope.client.name),` (same for every value) inside `$scope.list.push`. Please let me know if this is working.

Comment: Hi, thanks on the reply. I've tried it but yet the same result...

Comment: I see there is typo in your code. `ng-submit="addClient() ng-controller="displayClients""` should be `ng-submit="addClient()" ng-controller="displayClients"`.

Comment: again thank you, but its still not working